# calling batch file that calls yet another batch file fails

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file `a.bat` that effectively looks like this:

```
call some.bat

java -cp "saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform  abc.xml des.xsl > des.xml

call subfolder\other.bat
```

And the `other.bat` in `subfolder` effectively looks like this:

```
call yet_another_batch.bat

java -cp "../saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform any.xml try.xsl > try.xml
java -cp "../saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform ../some.xml test.xsl
```

So in the first file (`a.bat`), I call another batch file in the same folder and some xsl scripts in the same folder that write xml files into the same folder.
From the first batch script (`a.bat`) I'd like to call the `subfolder\other.bat`. However, when I do that, it fails to call the `yet_another_batch.bat` in `subfolder` and also the xsl scripts in `subfolder` and it doesnt find the saxon9he.jar.

What's the correct way to do this? Do I have to add the folder name to all the files referenced in the `subfolder\other.bat`? Seems a little cumbersome. I'm on Windows 7, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two lines lines to other.bat like this:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
call yet_another_batch.bat

java -cp "../saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform any.xml try.xsl > try.xml
java -cp "../saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform ../some.xml test.xsl
popd
```

Using [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html), other.bat will execute it's commands from it's own folder. [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) sets it back so the directory will not be changed when you return in `a.bat`